# What does the CR in iOS class names stand for?

Tags: ios, history

While searching for some missing libraries with CR in it's name I started wondering what is the legacy behind the "CR" in https://github.com/croberts22/CRNavigationController or some other frameworks out there?

Does it have to do with Reference Counting? Or is it something else?

Comment: It is authors initials.

Comment: Well the class you linked probably is prefixed against the author's username... In general classes are prefixed to prevent having different classes using the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's the class prefix. These are set on a per project basis, and you are prompted to set a class prefix when you start a new project in Xcode.

Here's the official word from Apple on class prefixes:

`Your own classes should use three letter prefixes. These might relate to a combination of your company name and your app name, or even a specific component within your app. As an example, if your company were called Whispering Oak, and you were developing a game called Zebra Surprise, you might choose WZS or WOZ as your class prefix.`

More can be found on the 
[Programming with Objective-C: Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) page.

Comment: Notice: "three letter prefixes" because Apple reserves two letter prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that the name of the author is Corey Roberts I'd guess that is the reason.

Comment: What about the other frameworks that have CR in it. Here is the link for CocaoPods search for CR

http://cocoapods.org/?q=name%3Acr

Comment: Oh on the other hand now that I looked at the name of the authors it is probably that, its just that I have seen CR around a lot of classes thought it was related to something from the past.

Answer (score 0):

It's a naming convention. In Objective-C we don't have namespaces (like in C++) so to avoid name collisions libraries' authors add their initials as a prefix of classes.